# Open file inside docker container has been shut down

Tags: docker, docker-container

I start a mysql container and change the config file inside a container, in this case is `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. And restart container.

Maybe something wrong with that config file and the container cannot start. How can I edit that config file when the container has been shutdown?

Comment: A container is immutable, your changes and conf are gone. You should use a Dockerfile to build an image and include my.cnf.

Comment: or commit your changes, see `docker commit`, the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/ but the Dockerfile helps you easily build a new image

Comment: oh, thank you, but I'm not going to change the container, I just want to get a file in a container has been shutdown and cannot start again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A container is immutable, your changes and conf are gone. You should use a Dockerfile to build a custom image and include my.cnf.

It can be easily done, create a folder, create my.cnf in it and a Dockerfile with only two lines

```
FROM mysql
ADD my.cnf /path/to/mysql/conf/folder # replace with the path where you'd usually put the conf file
```

Now build and run:

```
docker build -t custom_mysql .
docker run custom_mysql // << add the run options you need/want (exposed port for example or container name)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not going to change the container, I just want to get a file in a container has been shut down and cannot start again.

Comment: @Finn Like I said, your file is gone. Immutable means when a container is stopped/restarted, it's reverted to its initial state, every change made (new files for example) is gone forever. A container is not a VM, it's disposable, you didn't use a custom image so no need to cling to it, delete it, create another and this time, be aware that your changes are temporary only.

Comment: Thank you, I'm understood and accepted your answer :D